# Error CS1513: } expected

Tags: c#

```
private static class <FindAndClickAds>o__SiteContainer1
{
    public static CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, IHTMLWindow2>> <>p__Site2;
}
```

When I try to compile this in C#, I get the following message:

> Error CS1513: } expected at the line  o__SiteContainer1

Why am I getting this error? How do I fix it?

Comment: `<>p__Site2` is not a valid C# identifier. Has this come from decompiled code?

Comment: I'm admittedly unfamiliar with C#, but does C# allow for generics in that order? In Java, I'd expect to see `o__SiteContainer1<FindAndClickAds>` instead of `<FindAndClickAds>o__SiteContainer1`.

Comment: Yes its came from Decompiled code

Comment: @Lee Thanks for your comments.. Hope you are correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<FindAndClickAds>o__SiteContainer1` and `<>p__Site2` are not valid C# identifiers. It looks like this has been decompiled and are compiler-generated class names. You should change the names to use valid identifiers e.g.

```
private static class FindAndClickAdso__SiteContainer1
{
    public static CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, IHTMLWindow2>> p__Site2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should probably be this :

```
public static CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, IHTMLWindow2>> p__Site2;
```

Comment: I already removed and tried but no luck.. Still getting the error in between <FindAndClickAds>o__SiteContainer1

Comment: @Matrix: That syntax is invalid I think.  You need to use generic after. Usually a T.